# How do I change the community string of an snmp device?

Tags: snmp

I have many snmp devices that has their community string set to "public".
Is there a way to change the community string of an snmp device?

Comment: `Is there a way to change the community string of an snmp device?` Yes.

Comment: It's a per-device configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's just a conceptual question (As you don't provide us any information regarding the type of devices you are trying to configure)

So the answer is:

**Sure!, there is a way to change SNMP community in almost any device**. Such way depends on the device you are configuring (Network devices, workstations, servers ...)

For example, if you are configuring a linux machine:

1. Edit snmpd config file (normally located in /etc/snmpd) and change *rocommunity* and *rwcommunity* parameters.
2. Restart the snmp daemon.